Prototyping IMAP connection to outlook365 server using openssl
I am trying to test connection to Outlook365 IMAP server.
As I understood. The first step should be to obtain access_token using my client_id and client_secret.
I got it using Postman
access_token from Postman
Then, using this access token, I constructed base64 string
Using PHP:
base64_encode("user=" . $email . "\x01auth=Bearer " . $accessToken . "\x01\x01")

Finally, I used the result base64 string in openssl terminal.
Openssl version OpenSSL 3.4.0 22 Oct 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.4.0 22 Oct 2024)
> openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:993

...
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.

> A01 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 <base64 string from PHP script above>

( ~30-60s later )

* BYE Connection is closed. 13
SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:688

Is my authentication flow bad ? Does this error signalize something else entirely ?
Thank you for any advice

You need to add “-crlf” to your command line to terminate your commands correctly.  It’s waiting because it didn’t see that your command was finished.
openssl s_client -crlf -connect outlook.office365.com:993

tyvm for your suggestion, now upon entering command A01 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 <token> I see at least response A01 NO AUTHENTICATE failed. which is progress. Before I couldn't see what's the problem. Now I have to figure out what's wrong with my base64-encoded key. I guess there's still problem with how I compose it ..

Lots of things: is your token less then an hour old?  Does it have the proper scopes (see related questions)…
